# Not getting the desired result in laravel fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello friends I am trying to fetch data in laravel but I am getting the error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `publications`.*, `education`.`research_area` from `education` inner join `publications` on `education`.`user_id` = `publications`.`user_id` where `users`.`id` = 5). Please help.
My controller is given.

```
public function publicationpdf()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $data['data'] = DB::table('education') ->join('publications', 'education.user_id', '=', 'publications.user_id')->select('publications.*','education.research_area') ->where('users.id',$user_id)
            ->get();
        if(count ($data)>0){
            return view('pdf/publicationpdf',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            return view('pdf/publicationpdf');
        }
    }
```

I am not getting the desired result. while using 'publication.user_id',$user_id, I am getting the following result.
[image: result in view]

While I have only two rows of the current login user in publications table given picture.
[image: publications table in database]

Comment: Please update your question by showing table structure for all tables, sample input, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The `users` table does not appear in your query.  Presumably you should be referring to the `publications.user_id` column:

```
$data['data'] = DB::table('education')
    ->join('publications', 'education.user_id', '=', 'publications.user_id')
    ->select('publications.*', 'education.research_area')
    ->where('publications.user_id', $user_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: It works but I am not getting the desired result. I want to display all the publications of current login user with research_area. It gives me different result as i am going to post in pictures above in question.

Comment: This is the best answer I could give based on your limited information.  Add data to your question for best results.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('education') ->join('publications', 'education.user_id', '=', 'publications.user_id')->select('publications.*','education.research_area') ->where('users.id',$user_id)
        ->get();
```

if you have column `user_id` in `education` table. then just use `->where('user_id',$user_id)` instead `->where('users.id',$user_id)`

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `publications`.*, `education`.`research_area` from `education` inner join `publications` on `education`.`user_id` = `publications`.`user_id` where `user_id` = 5)

Comment: try to add `->select('publications.*','education.user_id','education.research_area')`  Or if it is not the solution, try to put where() before joins

Answer (score 0):

Plese check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins)

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
$data['data'] = DB::table('education')
               ->join('publications', function ($join) use($user_id){
                  $join->on('education.id', '=', 'publications.user_id')
                       ->where('publications.user_id',$user_id);
               })
                  ->select('publications.*','education.research_area')
                  ->get();
```

but you have to change your database structure because there is no connection between **publications**  , **education** tables. from your **DB structure** each user can have many publications and many  education so which **publication** has which **education** is question ??